# Visualizar objeto 3D em aplicação Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, wpf, graphics

Bom dia, estou tentando inserir um objeto 3D em minha aplicação do tipo WinForms C#. Pesquisei e aparentemente o caminho mais fácil seria usar um controle WPF. Como eu posso integrar o controle WPF na minha aplicação WinForms? Ou, há alguma outra forma mais simples de inserir esse objeto no meu projeto?

Comment: Recomendo que estude migrar todo o seu projeto para WPF se for possível, e depois vai pensar pq não fez isso antes. Digo pq já estive nessa mesma situação e hoje não quero ver WinForm nem pintado de ouro.